# Why is this C# loop over a list of strings being weird?

Tags: c#, list, loops

I don't consider myself to be the greatest developer in the world, but I thought I could at least loop over a list of strings!

Here's my function:

```
    public string liststrings() {

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("First");
        strings.Add("Second");
        strings.Add("Third");

        string output = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++ )
        {
            output += output + strings[i] + "<br />";
        }

        return output;
    }
```

This function returns the following html:

```
First<br />
First<br />
Second<br />
First<br />
First<br />
Second<br />
Third<br />
```

Where are the extra iterations coming from?

FYI: I come from a primarily VB script background and I can do this with an array in VB script without a problem. What different about lists or C# syntax that's fouling this up?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Every once in a while, there's a question I don't answer even though the answer seems obvious to me - it would have ten answers by the time I finished my answer :)

Comment: Oh geez... I'm dumb... end of a long day...long week. ready to go home! Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Just to be clear, the loop is not being weird it is doing exactly what you tell it to do. :)

Comment: Yeah... I'm just not used to C#'s += assignment operator.

The funny thing is i didn't even want to build a string. I just wanted to make sure my form was being bound to the modl correctly... lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're adding output twice.

```
output += output + strings[i] + "<br />";
```

is equivalent to:

```
output = output + output + strings[i] + "<br />";
```

You could use:

```
output += strings[i] + "<br />";
```

A better option might be a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I think this answer was first... so checkmark. Thanks for the help... Kinda embarrasing...

Comment: imo, it doesn't matter which answer is first, it's who is best. In this case however, it doesn't matter since the first one was also a really good one :)

Comment: @quakkels You could also use `string output = string.Concat(strings.Select(s => s + "<br />"));`. Most of the time it's better to use `String.Join` or `String.Concat`, and then you won't have to write a loop or choose between `String` and `StringBuilder` for the variable.

Answer (score 7):

You are adding the whole string back to itself on each iteration, try the following instead:

```
output += strings[i] + "<br />";
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra iterations are coming from the fact that you are appending the previous value of output to itself twice.

```
output += output + strings[i] + "<br />";
```

I think you want

```
output = output + strings[i] + "<br />";
```

or

```
output += strings[i] + "<br />";
```

But honestly from what you are doing I would look at the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use a `StringBuilder` object instead of concatenating strings.

```
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    sb.WriteLine("{0}<br />", strings[i]);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Note to use the `.Length` property for pure arrays because it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the () after `strings.Count`. Also, you can use a

```
foreach(string str in strings)
{
    // etc.
}
```

Also, as mentioned in other posts, you are adding output twice:

```
output += output + "something"
```

is equivalent to

```
output = output + output + "something"
```